# Transaction Not Endorsed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

Transaction is not endorsed by the endorsers in the multiple organisations

Tried changing the endorsement policy from 3 orgs to 2 orgs to verify whether the transaction is working or not.

```
Unhandled error for request POST /api/TransferCommodityPossession:
Error: Error trying invoke business network with transaction id d5334feb70ba03629859f1e4b87d2a687c14f5a5300b3219ecf330d6d22ae5d9. 
Error: Peer localhost:7051 has rejected transaction 'd5334feb70ba03629859f1e4b87d2a687c14f5a5300b3219ecf330d6d22ae5d9' with code ENDORSEMENT_POLICY_FAILURE
```

Transaction should get executed which is being endorsed by the endorsers in the three different organizations in a single instance system such that the data gets updated in the couch db.

Comment: Please inform what is your actual policy and how you defined that. By the error your policy are not being reached.

Comment: {
    "identities": [
        {
            "role": {
                "name": "member",
                "mspId": "Org1MSP"
            }
        },
        {
            "role": {
                "name": "member",
                "mspId": "Org2MSP"
            }
        }
    ],
    "policy": {
        "2-of": [
            {
                "signed-by": 0
            },
            {
                "signed-by": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}

Comment: Try to increase the log level to Debug, it will provide more infos about the error. Are you using NodeSDK?

Comment: we are working on the project using composer hosted from the machine, so better need more info on that.